# Replace String with other value

Tags: android, xml, json, string

I'm getting String from a url like this

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"jewellery":{"Madurai":[{"id":"1","category":"Jewellery","type":"Silver","name":"Kallyan","banner":"","logo":"","about":"Kallyan Jewellery","contact":"Kallyan Jewellery","map":{"lat_long_1":{"latitude":"1.4875","longitude":"2.1547"}}},{"id":"2","category":"Jewellery","type":"Silver","name":"Kallayan Test","banner":"","logo":"","about":"Kallayan Test","contact":"Kallayan Test","map":{"lat_long_1":{"latitude":"24242","longitude":"2424"}}} ],"total":2} }
</string>
```

I need to delete  `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">` and  `</string>` 
 alone from the string. How can i do that?

I tried using `string.replace("","")`

Comment: What happened after you use the `string.replace("","");` Break the suspense...

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
yourstring = yourstring.replace(oldStringValue,newStringValue);
```

i.e.

```
yourstring = yourstring.replace("<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">","");
```

Comment: @AmarnathK if you got it right why don't you upvote it? It will help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String url =your string i.e. //<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"jewellery":{"Madurai":[{"id":"1","category":"Jewellery","type":"Silver","name":"Kallyan","banner":"","logo":"","about":"Kallyan Jewellery","contact":"Kallyan Jewellery","map":{"lat_long_1":{"latitude":"1.4875","longitude":"2.1547"}}},{"id":"2","category":"Jewellery","type":"Silver","name":"Kallayan Test","banner":"","logo":"","about":"Kallayan Test","contact":"Kallayan Test","map":{"lat_long_1":{"latitude":"24242","longitude":"2424"}}} ],"total":2} }
```

```
String suburl = url.substring(startpoint, endpoint);
```

In your case

```
String suburl = url.substring(37, 493);
```